# Proof that f : V* ⊗ W −→ HomK (V, W ) is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

If K is a field and V,W vector spaces how to prove that there is a function f : V* ⊗ W −→ HomK (V, W ) uniquely defined by the equation f (α ⊗ w)(v) = α(v)w and f is an isomorphism (if V and W are finite-dimensional)

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this question, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have

Comment: Pick a basis of V and a basis of W. From this there is a standard way to construct a basis of Hom(V, W). The latter also gives a standard way to construct a basis on V*, and thus together there is a standard construction of a basis of V* \otimes W. It’s not hard to see that your f passes one of these bases to the other (no matter what choice you made initially of basis of V and W).

Answer (score -1):

Note that the dimension of $Hom_k(V,W)$ is $dim V.dim W$

Further, since $V$ is finite dimensional, hence $V^{*} \cong V$.

Thus, $V^{*} \otimes_K W \cong K^{(dim V)} \otimes K^{(dim W)} \cong K^{(dim V.dim W)}$

since tensoring with any module commutes with direct sums.

Thus, both the domain and the codomain of $f$ have the same dimension.

Now, fix bases of V and W. It is easy to see that $f$ is surjective.

Rank Nullity theorem says that $f$ is an isomorphism.

(Side Remark : Note that $f$ is natural in both $V$ and $W$)